# Cannot assign "'Sample Category'": "Product.category" must be a "Category" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, mysql-python

****While creating new products I'm getting such kind of error. Can someone help me?****

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name_geo = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default='/placeholder.png')
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=False, default=0, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    countInStock = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_geo
```

```
class Category(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def createProduct(request):
    user = request.user
    
    product = Product.objects.create(
        user=user,
        name_geo="Sample Name",
        category="Sample Category",
        price=0,
        brand='Sample Brand',
        countInStock=0,
    )

    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Without separating category class in models.py everything works fine. I mean If i didn't use ForeignKey in Products class for category

Comment: Please remove `_id` from the category and then try

Comment: `AutoField` `PrimaryKey` will be generated automatically by django

Comment: Also, you must need to have at least 1 record in DB with `id` 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just has to be a Category Instance/Object

```py
product = Product.objects.create(
    user=user,
    name_geo="Sample Name",
    category=Category.objects.get_or_create(name="Sample Category"),
    price=0,
    brand='Sample Brand',
    countInStock=0,
)
```

**Notes:**

- You could just do a `.get()` or a `.filter().first()` if you don't want to create
- If you use a form, you can get away with just the Category's PK/_id in the POST

  - this type of thing: `f = form(request.POST)` `f.is_valid()` `f.save()`
- At the end that field will hold the PK/_id/Row# of the Category Obj

Comment: I used your advice and everything works fine if the category of products already exist but there are some error while creating new one. Error looks like this -> ValueError: Cannot assign "(<Category: techsad>, True)": "Product.category" must be a "Category" instance.

Comment: Oh shoot, I completely forgot that `get_or_create` returns two things like: `categoryObj, createdBool = Category.get_or_create()` I assume you already figured out a solution, but you'd just do that Category.get_or_create above the Product.Create